# How do you set a key with both cmd and ctrl in Emacs.app?

Tags: emacs, elisp

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-f") 'emmet-next-edit-point)`

When I hit `C-s-f`, I get the error `<C-s-268632070> is undefined`.

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-268632070") 'emmet-next-edit-point)`

When I evaluate, I get the error `C-s- must prefix a single character, not 268632070`

Emacs 24.2.1, latest OS X.

Comment: Try putting `C-s-268632070` into angle brackets (inside the quotes). I'm sure there's some nicer way than using that long number, which would make a better *answer*, but this works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place numerical key in angle brackets:

`(global-set-key (kbd "<C-s-268632070>") 'emmet-next-edit-point)`